# HTML Ajax Converting select option into buttons doesn't send parameters

Tags: html, ajax

I have this select option:

```
<select name="rank" id="rankvalue" onChange="rank({{$thisData->id}})">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

which is calling this Ajax:

```
function rank(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{ url('do_sort') }}"+"/"+id,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: $('#rankvalue').serialize(),
        success: function(data){   
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to convert them into three buttons like this

```
<div name="rank" id="rankvalue" onClick="rank({{$thisData->id}})">
    <button value="1">1</button>
    <button value="2">2</button>
    <button value="3">3</button>
</div>
```

But the parameter doesn't get sent.

I have tried moving name, id, and onClick on each button, any combination I can think of, but it still doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Note: I'm not looking for CSS solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the value from function rank() instead:

```
<div>
    <button onClick="rank({{$thisData->id}},1)">1</button>
    <button onClick="rank({{$thisData->id}},2)">2</button>
    <button onClick="rank({{$thisData->id}},3)">3</button>
</div>
```

Then form the json in ajax.

```
function rank(id,value)
{
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{{ url('do_sort') }}"+"/"+id,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            'rank': value
        },
        success: function(data){   
            //$("#contentdata").load(" #contentdata");
            console.log(data);
            getRank();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```